# Using Roboflow in VS Code

Tags: roboflow

I am working on a computer vision project using roboflow. I am trying to import the roboflow package into VS code but am having difficulties. Any ideas on how to solve this?

Tried to Youtube solutions but couldn't find anything

Answer (score 0):

What error did you receive when trying to import the package? If the package name has a yellow line under it, that means you have not installed the package. You can install it using `pip install roboflow` in your terminal.